# Django Form 2 Stages

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make a Django order system that requires 2 forms. The first form, lets users choose some some quantities and basic contact info some. Then, using the quantities of each item they ordered I generate a 2nd form which allows them to choose some options for each item. This system is specifically for event tickets. Here are the 2 stages:

1) Get the order info such as name, address, phone of the person placing the order. Also find out how many people are coming to each of the possible events.

2) Based on the number of people per event, get their name and e-mail address.

I already have both forms created. I am just getting tripped up in the views. When they submit form 1, I need to take that info and save some of it and then send them to form 2. At form 2, they will fill out the rest of the info and finish processing.

How would you set up the views in such as case? I essentially nee-d to call on view form another and pass data between. I tried using kwargs, but I have trouble processing the second form.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your models, it's hard to give an exact solution, but one approach is to have two separate views, one for each form.

Once you've processed the first form, you're most likely going to have an instance of some object that you created from the first form. It sounds like you just need to pass the id of that object to your next view where you could then get that object and do whatever association you need.

Also, it sounds like you might need to be collecting data from several instances of a form...

> (2) Based on the number of people per event, get their name and e-mail
>   address.)

You'll want to use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/) for that.